# Can you use Electrum wallets for storing Ethereum?

Tags: electrum

Can Electrum wallets be used to store Ether?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use Electrum wallets to store Ether. As stated in the [FAQ](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#does-electrum-support-altcoins-cryptocurrencies)) Electrum only supports Bitcoin.

Comment: electrum also support ltc

Comment: @JimThio Electrum-LTC does. Electrum doesn't. Electrum-LTC is not Electrum but a fork of it. You still can't store Litcoin and Bitcoin in the same Electrum wallet, you can't even use the same client for both. Furthermore, afaik, there is no such fork for Ether.

Comment: FunFact: You can use Electrum to hold/spend Tether USDT (Omni). If you know the drill :)